ffmpeg - How do I convert audio while preserving its bitrate?
I want to convert audio downloaded from YouTube (in OPUS codec) to OGG, but when I do this using the basic ffmpeg -i -vn <file> command, there is a slight decrease in bitrate (as an example, 131kb/s to 115 kb/s). Is there a way to prevent this without manually checking the bitrate on each file and enforcing it in the command?

Is there a decrease in the quality? Or, to put it another way, do you know that this decrease in bitrate is a bad/undesireable thing?

Vorbis is only VBR.  Leave them as opus, as it supports CBR if you need to downsample.
